# Keyboard listener can't change this.state

Tags: react-native

I want an animation to be executed when i open my keyboard and revert back when I close it.

The problem is:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.scaleValue')

I have Keyboard.listener which works good.

State:

```
this.state = {
      scaleValue: new Animated.Value(0),
    }
```

Animated View

```
<Animated.View style={styles.logoContainer,
  {
      transform: [
          {scale: logoScale}
      ]
  }
}>
  <Image source={require('./someimage.png')} style={{width: 64, height: 64}} />
</Animated.View>
```

Interpolate

```
const logoScale = this.state.scaleValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 0.5, 1],
      outputRange: [1, 0.5, 0]
    });
```

Trigger

```
  _keyboardDidShow () {
    this.state.scaleValue.setValue(0);
    Animated.timing(
        this.state.ScaleValue,
        {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 300,
          easing: Easing.easeOutBack
        }
    ).start();
  }
```

So, when I put the code from trigger into a function and call it onPress with Touchable, it works.

Comment: `this` is not the same context inside the function supplied to `Animated.timing`. You need to bind: `this._keyboardDidShow = this._keyboardDidShow.bind(this)` If that doesn't work you could probably even set `let me = this` above the call to `timing` (and refer to it as `me` within the method).

Comment: @G0dsquad You're right. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I've therefore added it as an answer for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` does not have the same context inside the function supplied to `Animated.timing`.

You need to bind the method:

`this._keyboardDidShow = this._keyboardDidShow.bind(this)`

If that doesn't work you could probably even set `let me = this` above the call to `timing` (and refer to it as `me` within the body of the `timing` method call).

Comment: You can use ES6 arrow functions too. `this` within an arrow function is automatically set to the outer scope (which is the Component).

Comment: Indeed you can, feel free to edit this into the answer if you like